# Searching and appending concatenated strings

Tags: string, algorithm, search

I have a file which contains concatenated strings.

`find_or_add(string)` either:

- returns the offset of an occurrence of the string in the file (not necessarily the first)
- adds as much of the tail of the string to the file as necessary for the file to contain the string (and then returns the offset of the string in the file).

pseudocode:

```
file.init()                // file == ""
file.find_or_add("cat")    // file == "cat", returns 0
file.find_or_add("able")   // file == "catable", returns 3
file.find_or_add("table")  // file == "catable", returns 2
file.find_or_add("tables") // file == "catables", returns 2
file.find_or_add("spigot") // file == "catablespigot", returns 7
file.find_or_add("pig")    // file == "catablespigot", returns 8
```

What algorithm/structure should I be looking at to 'summarise' this file in memory, and allow the required operations in at most O(log N)?

Assume that the file is bigger than RAM.

Language is not important, but I can read Pseudocode, C, Java, Python, Javascript and Haskell.

Comment: What about a [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree)? You could find in O(RequestStringLength) if it is already prefix of an existing suffix or how much you many character extend the file. Createinon of the tree would need O(filelength) but searching in it will be quite fast: O(RequestStringLength).

Comment: @MrSmith42 If the file doesn't fit in RAM, I don't suppose a suffix tree will either.

Comment: ... except that this file will have quite a bit of duplication, in which case the suffix tree may use less memory and thus fit in RAM, though there's no way to know whether it will with the information provided.

Answer (score 1):

If your inserts are small then you can build a suffix tree or suffix array (using a lazy implementation). Since the inserts are < k you only need to build the tree up to that depth and the structure will only take limited memory.

**edit: if you have to store the suffix ids (=integers) it won't fit in memory if the text doesn't unfortunately**

The suffix tree (or suffix array which is more compact) then represents all substrings of your text and then you can do simple lookup:

Is the substring in the tree?

Yes -> return the suffix (which is in the leafs of the tree).

No -> add it and append the text to your source file.

I am willing to go deeper into this but I have to know about the pattern sizes first.

EDIT: Note that an insert then only takes O(k) time!

EDIT2: If the patterns are not limitted in length then you might have to build the full tree which is O(N) in space and time, the problem is that you usually have a factor > 10bytes/char then.
Regards, irW

Comment: k is the length of the longest insert

Comment: I am currently thinking that Suffix trees might still be problematic. You have to store all IDs and since your text string doesn't fit into memory, all those IDs won't either, so we'll have to think about something on disk I am afraid.

Answer (score 1):

The suffix array and suffix tree will probably induce memory problems. (they always are larger then the text, even if you cut them at a certain depth since you need to store all suffixIDs in your structure).

You could create a set of files which represent the IDs of certain prefixes. Say we store all length 2 prefixes in a different file and keep it sorted. This file will contain on average 1/26^2 of the suffix ids. So we have a file aa.txt , ab.txt and so fort. The entries in the file we keep sorted (Suffix Array). Each time you want to do a lookup you use load this small file, which is already sorted and check. The complexity would be O(N) (you have to load the file which is a constant controllable fraction of your text) but you can tune the prefactor for best performance. In a 5 Gb file for example if you use length 2 prefixes then there you will have a set of 8 Mb sized files, for prefixLength 3 you will be around 320 kb and so fort..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this isn't applicable, but [this technology and algorithm](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Rb85cOXTKU) has O(log N) search, fast insertion and is optimized heavily for efficient IO with large data sets. I could be wrong, but it feels like a good balance between insertion and search. What do you think?

Comment: Posts should be self-contained (not dependent on YouTube or any other website). Please explain the algorithm in sufficient detail to be understood without watching the video or make this a comment on the question instead. If you add an explanation, feel free to leave the link there in addition to the explanation.

Comment: This is a very valuable lecture. It explains the algorithm in much more detail than I ever could here. I've tried to summarize it in relation to the question. Sometimes answers aren't simple enough to explain in just a few lines or paragraphs (as I feel is the case here).